# Prevent subdomain from Google search

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, subdomain, google-search

We have site enabled with subdomain and these subdomain names are created by end users.

Consider the parent site as **www.mysite.com** and there can be different subdomains like **a.mysite.com** , **b.mysite.com** etc

I want to prevent specific subdomains from appearing in google search. i.e I want **a.mysite.com** listed in google search but I do not want **b.subdomain.com**

The root folder is common for all the subdomains.

Answer (score 0):

In your Master Page, add a `meta`-tag with the name `robots`. Fill the value, in Page Load, dynamically, according to the requested subdomain.